# how to update the position of the gridview in android

Tags: android, gridview, android-recyclerview

Hi in the below code I have a search and gridview .If user type for charcter it is getting the results based on search letter.After displaying gridview data click on it evrytime giving me first position data.

For example : gridview data contains ravi,rajesh,manu.Now in search bar i typed ma so my result should be manu as griditem.Now i click on manu it is giving me ravi results.

How to update the position of the gridview

Can any one help me why it is not working

activity_main.xml:

```
<EditText
android:layout_width="325dp"
android:layout_height="53dp"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:id="@+id/search"
android:background="@drawable/rectangle_border_white"
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_round_search_24"
android:gravity="center"
android:padding="16dp"
android:hint="Search by doctor or speciality"
android:textColorHint="@color/dark_blue">
</EditText>

gridview:
    <GridView
android:id="@+id/gridlayout"
android:numColumns="3"
android:gravity="center"
android:columnWidth="100dp"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
                </GridView>
```

search.java:

```
search.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                }
                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                        speclializationAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                }
        });

Adapter.java:

    @Override
        public Filter getFilter() {
            return new Filter() {
                @Override
                protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
                    String charString = charSequence.toString();
                    if (charString.isEmpty()) {
                        mFilteredList = doctorListModels;
                    } else {
                        ArrayList<DataList> filteredList = new ArrayList<>()
                        for (DataList androidVersion : doctorListModels) {
    
                            if (androidVersion.getSpecialization().toLowerCase().contains(charString)) {
    
                                filteredList.add(androidVersion);
    
    
                            }
                        }
    
                        mFilteredList = filteredList;
                    }
    
                    FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                    filterResults.values = mFilteredList;
                    return filterResults;
                }
    
                @Override
                protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
                    mFilteredList = (ArrayList<DataList>) filterResults.values;
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            };
        }

onitem for gridview:

    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                       // speclialistimage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.like_button);
                        clickListener.myItemClick(i);
  });

Fragment.java:
  

    @Override
            public void myItemClick(final int i) {
                doctorlists_spe.clear();
                final String speclname = specilaistlist.get(i).getSpecialization();//everytime I am getting the poston as 0
                String hospital_id = "PH-193";
                final APIService service = RetroClass.getRetrofitInstance().create(APIService.class);
                Call<DoctorListModel> call = service.GetDoctorList(hospital_id);
                Log.wtf("URL Called", call.request().url() + "");
                call.enqueue(new Callback<DoctorListModel>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<DoctorListModel> call, Response<DoctorListModel> response) {
                        Log.e("response", new Gson().toJson(response.body()));
                        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.e("response", new Gson().toJson(response.body()));
                            DoctorListModel doctorListModel = response.body();
                            dataLists = doctorListModel.getDataLists();
                            for (DataList dataList : dataLists) {
                                specilization = dataList.getSpecialization();
                                dataList1 = new DataList(specilization);
                                ArrayList<Doctorlist> doctorlists = dataList.getData();
                                boolean istrue = false;
                                for (Doctorlist doctorlist : doctorlists) {
                                    Specialization = doctorlist.getSpecialization();
                                    DoctorName = doctorlist.getDoctorName();
                                    Qualification = doctorlist.getQualification();
                                    Experience = doctorlist.getExperience();
                                    LanguagesKnown = doctorlist.getLanguagesKnown();
                                    Hospital = doctorlist.getHospital();
                                    ConsultationFees = doctorlist.getConsultationFees();
                                    ProfllePhoto = doctorlist.getProfllePhoto();
                                    HospitalID = doctorlist.getHospitalID();
                                    DoctorID = doctorlist.getDoctorID();
                                    String rupee = getResources().getString(R.string.Rs);
                                    Doctorlist doctorlist2 = new Doctorlist(Specialization, DoctorName, Qualification, Experience, LanguagesKnown, ProfllePhoto, rupee.concat(" ").concat(ConsultationFees), Hospital, HospitalID, DoctorID);
                                    doctortext.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    if (dataList1.getSpecialization().equals(speclname)) {
        
                                        doctorlists_spe.add(doctorlist2);
                                        doctorAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                    } else {
        
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<DoctorListModel> call, Throwable t) {
                        Log.d("error", t.getMessage());
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue ,instead of position I was passed direct name.Then My issue got resolved.

String specilaity_name=mFilteredList.get(i).getSpecialization();
clickListener.myItemClick(specilaity_name);